# Как строку разбить по пробелам на переменные?

Tags: python, python-3.6

Как строку разбить по пробелам на переменные?
У меня есть строка

```
4032 example@outlook.com Alexandr
```

Как мне разбить его на переменные по пробелам?
Я имею ввиду что разделителем здесь служит пробел.
`4032` - должна быть переменная `number`, `example@outlook.com` - переменная `email`, `Alexandr` - переменная `name`.

Answer (score 1):

```
'4032 example@outlook.com Alexandr'.split()
```

вернет вам список из элементов с разбиением по пробелам.

Тогда можно получить значения так:

```
s = '4032 example@outlook.com Alexandr'
number = int(s.split()[0])
email = s.split()[1]
name = s.split()[2]
```

Comment: Или так: `number, email, name = s.split()`

Comment: @insolor Если `name` будет из нескольких слов, то будет ошибка. Лучше так: `s.split(maxsplit=2)` (разбиваем только по первым двум пробелам).

Comment: Спасибо, я решил свой вопрос!

Comment: @DirBeer тогда примите его как верный(галочка такая)